# how to create same method to execute for multiple requests without synchronization

Tags: java, spring, aop

I am using spring 3.0 and I am trying to make such application which contains 10 buttons. Each button serves different request but calling function is same with different types of parameters. Now my question is, is there any way by which we can use same method over multiple requests? I don't want to synchronize that method because method needs more time to execute and it cant wait for next request. Or any alternate solution from scratch? Can AOP concept suits this kind of scenario? If yes then How?

Comment: Forget all the assumptions you have and go re-read how objects, methods, and the arguments used to invoke them work. Then review what purpose synchronization serves.

Comment: I suggest you read up on [Thread-local storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage).

Comment: From my understanding for each web request a new thread is created by the container to execute a request. Hence if you create your bean as request scoped then everything is java style I mean object instance creation, execution blah blah so why do you need to complicate solution as you already said sync is not required.